How to identify a/the problematic tuple in insert..select?
I am writing a plpgsql function that accepts a jsonb (array of objects), passed as Ppurchases::jsonb param, intended for batch insert using INSERT ... SELECT:
WITH purchases (createdtime,purchaseid,locationid,customerid,subtotal) AS (
  SELECT
    (purchasejson->>'createdtime')::timestamp,
    (purchasejson->>'purchaseid' )::int8,
    (purchasejson->>'locationid' )::int8,
    (purchasejson->>'customerid' )::int8,
    (purchasejson->>'subtotal'   )::numeric
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(Ppurchases) AS purchasejson
) INSERT INTO event.purchases (createdtime,purchaseid,locationid,customerid,subtotal)
SELECT createdtime,purchaseid,locationid,customerid,subtotal
FROM purchases;

My problem is that it is possible there may be one or more problematic rows attempting to be inserted. And, given such an error in transaction, the whole thing is rolled-back - and that is fine. But I would love to be able to communicate back to the caller (of the function), which row(s), in specific, had issue so they can decide if that row should be retried (or not).
I've looked at ON CONFLICT but I have yet to be able to find a way forward with that. I am happy to raise my own exception but I can't see how I can pull the information about which attempted insert-row failed so that I can communicate that back in the exception message.
Any ideas are greatly appreciated,
Rein

If those match, you can use jsonb_populate_recordset() to automagically map your purchasejson to rows of purchases, without having to type out all the (j->>'k')::t. The problematic rows are just duplicates violating a unique constraint, or is that something else, like invalid json, violating a check constraint, etc?


You can use jsonb_populate_recordset() to automagically map your purchasejson to rows of purchases.
ON CONFLICT works off a unique index. If your rows are problematic in some other way than violating unique, it won't be of much help.

Demo at db<>fiddle
WITH new_purchases AS(
  SELECT(jsonb_populate_recordset(null::event.purchases,:Ppurchases)).*
)
,inserted AS(
  INSERT INTO event.purchases 
  TABLE new_purchases
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
  RETURNING *
)
TABLE new_purchases
EXCEPT 
TABLE inserted;

You can also iterate over your batch, run your validations for each individual row, attempt the insert, catch and ignore the exception, instead only sending a notice with the values that refused to get in, or making the function return the rejects:
CREATE FUNCTION insert_into_purchases_returning_rejects(new_purchases jsonb)
  RETURNS SETOF event.purchases AS $f$
DECLARE rec event.purchases;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT(jsonb_populate_recordset(null::event.purchases,new_purchases)).* 
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO event.purchases (a,b)
            SELECT rec.*;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
            RETURN NEXT rec;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


Thanks @Zegarek, really great answer (including an excellent fiddle!). It looks to me like the 1st solution using ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING is likely to be more performant (than the LOOP in the second solution). But perhaps the difference is trivial - would you have any advice there?
Then, of course, given that the json could have bad data, the second solution is superior for catching the problem of bad json gracefully. It's a tough decision but I'd prefer the second solution if the performance hit were negligible. I'm working on benchmarking it so i will bring back some numbers.

The PL/pgSQL example is there only in case you're dealing with some specific type of invalidity other than rows not being unique - you can rely on that being way slower. See this example: a batch of the same 100k records where only 10% is unique takes 7.2s using the procedural block, almost 5x what the plain SQL statement needs at 1.5s.
